# specialize a template class for a template function

Tags: c++, templates

I have two template classes like

```
template <class T>
class MyClass1{};

template <class T>
class MyClass2{};
```

and I have a template function using them as an argument. The classes are specialized with std::string:

```
template <template class<std::string> T> myMethod(T<std::string>& arg){}
```

I'd like to use myMethod(objectOfMyClass1) and myMethod(objectOfMyClass2), but the code doesn't compile. How to specialize a template class for a template function?

Comment: `myMethod` is declared to have no arguments, but you're calling it with an argument?

Comment: "Doesn't compile" is rather wide term, isn't it?

Comment: @Griwes I'm sure that it's caused by my declaration of the function. I'm not sure how to write it.

Comment: @MuQiao, why not just paste that magical thing called ***error message*** here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a compilable example

```
template <class T>
class MyClass1{};

template <class T>
class MyClass2{};

template <template <typename> class T> 
void myMethod(T<std::string>& arg){}

int main()
{
MyClass1<std::string> c1;
myMethod(c1);
MyClass1<std::string> c2;
myMethod(c2);
}
```

Comment: yes the code compiles now. But when I move the function definition to the header, it doesn't compile again.

Comment: Could you add the information why I should use <typename> there instead the real type?

Comment: @MuQiao: such is the syntax defined in the standard. `template <typename> class T` tells that template parameter T is a template class, and the real template parameter is defined by the function argument type.

Answer (score 2):

First, if your method does not take any arguments, you won't be able to call it as you want.

Second, `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` are not classes but class templates -- you cannot therefore have `objectOfMyClass1` and `objectOfMyClass2`.

If you your function to behave specially for an argument of any type of the form `SomeClassTemplate<std::string>`, then what you're after is partial function template specialization, which is not allowed in C++. You will have to use a partially-specialized class instead:

```
template <class T>
struct MyMethodCall;

template <template <typename> class T>
struct MyMethodCall<T<std::string> > {
  static void call(T<std::string> object) {
    ...
  }
};

template <class T>
void myMethod(T & object) {
  MyMethodCall<T>::call(object);
}
```